# squid routing from nat machine to allow only a single https domain

Tags: iptables, squid

I have a public and private subnet on my network and I'm routing all traffic on my private subnet through a NAT machine on the public subnet. On the NAT machine, I have configured the squid proxy server so that I'm allowing the https connection only to a particular domain (let's say google.com). An excerpt from my squid configuration is as below:

`acl allowed_https_sites ssl::server_name google.com`

On my iptables rules, I add the below rules according to my squid configuration. The rules are:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3130
sudo service iptables save
```

From within the private subnet machine, if I try to navigate to `google.com` it works and if I navigate to any other https website, I am not able to access it which is exactly what I want.

I want to take it to one more step where I don't want any kind of outbound connections other than to `google.com` possible from my NAT machine as well. To achieve this, I am trying to implement a solution as discussed in this [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138013/routing-internet-on-nat-server-thru-squid-proxy) but am not getting the desired results.

If I modify the rules accordingly as mentioned on the above link, I'm not able to achieve the end result. The end result I'm trying to achieve is allow only a single https domain from my machine in the private subnet and rest everything should be blocked/rejected. At first I thought, I could do a simple string match on iptables rules but I was mistaken. This seems more challenging than I originally anticipated. Any other ideas that I could try out or I can somehow tweak the above solution to fit my usecase?

Answer (score 1):

Main Challenge is the fact that you don't have a specific address or range for google.com, by which iptables can work. Therefore you should block traffic at process level. As squid proxy mainly runs by 'squid' as effective user, you can disallow outgoing (OUTPUT) traffic from other processes.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner ! --uid-owner squid -j DROP
```

Furthermore, you can redirect any outgoing (but that of squid) towards squid and enjoy your previous config, in order to access only and only a single domain.